# Using specific jquery google library for wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I'm creating a basic plugin that allows me to add columns, accordions, and tabs. Everything is working fine but my tabs and accordions require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js

How do I add this jquery library to my plugin? My code is below.

```
<?php
   /*
   Plugin Name: Everypraise Plugin
   Plugin URI: http://breonwilliams.com
   Description: adds a button to your editor to allow you to add basic shortcodes like buttons and columns
   Version: 1.2
   Author: Breon Williams
   Author URI: http://breonwilliams.com
   License: GPL2
   */

/* Variables */
$everypraise_shortcodes_path = dirname(__FILE__);
$everypraise_shortcodes_main_file = dirname(__FILE__).'/everypraiseplugin.php';
$everypraise_shortcodes_directory = plugin_dir_url($everypraise_shortcodes_main_file);
$everypraise_shortcodes_name = "Everypraise Plugin";








/* Add shortcodes scripts file */
function everypraise_shortcodes_add_scripts() {
    global $everypraise_shortcodes_directory, $everypraise_shortcodes_path;
    if(!is_admin()) {

        /* Includes */
        include($everypraise_shortcodes_path.'/assets/functions.php');

        wp_enqueue_style('everypraise_shortcodes', $everypraise_shortcodes_directory.'/assets/css/shortcodes.css');






            wp_enqueue_script('jquery');




        wp_register_script('footerjs', $everypraise_shortcodes_directory.'assets/js/my-footer-scripts.js', 'jquery','1.0',true);
        wp_register_script('easing', $everypraise_shortcodes_directory.'assets/js/jquery.easing.min.js', 'jquery','1.0',true);


        wp_enqueue_script('footerjs');
        wp_enqueue_script('easing');

    } else {

        wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker' );

    }

    /* Font Awesome */
    wp_enqueue_style('everypraise_shortcodes_fontawesome', $everypraise_shortcodes_directory.'/fonts/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('everypraise_shortcodes_fontello', $everypraise_shortcodes_directory.'/fonts/fontello/css/fontello.css');

}
add_filter('init', 'everypraise_shortcodes_add_scripts');

// Add Formats Dropdown Menu To MCE
if ( ! function_exists( 'wpex_style_select' ) ) {
    function wpex_style_select( $buttons ) {
        array_push( $buttons, 'styleselect' );
        return $buttons;
    }
}
add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'wpex_style_select' );



// Hooks your functions into the correct filters
function my_add_mce_button() {
    // check user permissions
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) && !current_user_can( 'edit_pages' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    // check if WYSIWYG is enabled
    if ( 'true' == get_user_option( 'rich_editing' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'my_add_tinymce_plugin' );
        add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'my_register_mce_button' );
    }
}
add_action('admin_head', 'my_add_mce_button');

// Declare script for new button
function my_add_tinymce_plugin( $plugin_array ) {

    $plugin_array['my_mce_button'] = plugins_url( '/assets/js/mce-button.js', __FILE__ );

    return $plugin_array;
}

// Register new button in the editor
function my_register_mce_button( $buttons ) {
    array_push( $buttons, 'my_mce_button' );
    return $buttons;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); //disable the stock jQuery
wp_register_script( 'google_jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true ); //register the new version
wp_enqueue_script( 'google_jquery' ); //load the new version
```

If you will be using other scripts that use jQuery as a dependency, you should specify it.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_other_script', 'path/to/script', array( 'google_jquery' ), null, true );
```